# How to convert JSON to Prometheus time-series friendly data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, formatting, time-series

Using PowerShell to hit a third party API and return data in JSON I would like to format that response in a Prometheus time-series friendly format.

Prometheus formatting example:

```
<metric name>{<label name>=<label value>, ...}
```

Getting the data from the API into PS is no issue but I am a bit lost on how to transform it. Here is an example of the JSON response

```json
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "Name": "HomeOffice1",
        "icmpmfs": {
          "icmpresults": [
            {
              "im_AvgResponseTime": "20.2"
            }
          ]
        },
        "portmfs": {
          "portdata": [
            {
              "im_Availability": "100.0",
              "im_Utilization": "0.129264109333333"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "HomeOffice2",
        "icmpmfs": {
          "icmpresults": [
            {
              "im_AvgResponseTime": "64.8"
            }
          ]
        },
        "portmfs": {
          "portdata": [
            {
              "im_Availability": "100.0",
              "im_Utilization": "0.266945682666667"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "HomeOffice3",
        "icmpmfs": {
          "icmpresults": []
        },
        "portmfs": {
          "portdata": [
            {
              "im_Availability": "100.0",
              "im_Utilization": "0.114650546666667"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "HomeOffice4",
        "icmpmfs": {
          "icmpresults": []
        },
        "portmfs": {
          "portdata": [
            {
              "im_Availability": "100.0",
              "im_Utilization": "5.95813333333333E-4"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "HomeOffice5",
        "icmpmfs": {
          "icmpresults": [
            {
              "im_AvgResponseTime": "73.6"
            }
          ]
        },
        "portmfs": {
          "portdata": [
            {
              "im_Availability": "100.0",
              "im_Utilization": "0.0743622133333333"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I convert this response in PowerShell I can add labels to pull the nested JSON up to look like this:

```
$Results = $Obj.d.results |
           Select Name, @{Label="Utilization";Expression={$_.portmfs.portdata.im_Utilization}},
               @{Label="Availability";Expression={$_.portmfs.portdata.im_Availability}},
               @{Label="AvgResponse";Expression={$_.icmpmfs.icmpresults.im_AvgResponseTime}}
```

```
Name         : HomeOffice1
Utilization  : 0.129264109333333
Availability : 100.0
AvgResponse  : 20.2

Name         : HomeOffice2
Utilization  : 0.266945682666667
Availability : 100.0
AvgResponse  : 64.8

Name         : HomeOffice3
Utilization  : 0.114650546666667
Availability : 100.0
AvgResponse  : 

Name         : HomeOffice4
Utilization  : 5.95813333333333E-4
Availability : 100.0
AvgResponse  : 

Name         : HomeOffice5
Utilization  : 0.0743622133333333
Availability : 100.0
AvgResponse  : 73.6
```

To match the Prometheus format I would need to output each HomeOffice as it's own metric name with values like this:

```
HomeOffice1{Utilization,Availability,AvgResponse=0.129264109333333,100.0,20.2}
```

I'm having trouble looping through the JSON or PowerShell object and writing this out in the above format.

Comment: You could use string formatting to do it: `$Results | ForEach-Object{ "<{0}>{{Utilization,Availability,AvgResponse={1},{2},{3}}}" -f $_.Name,$_.Utilization,$_.Availability,$_.AvgResponse }`

Comment: Thank's so much for your feedback - this worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the module [PS Gallery - PrometheusExporter](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PrometheusExporter)

```
Import-Module PrometheusExporter

$OfficeUtilizationMetricDesc = New-MetricDescriptor `
  -Name 'Utilization' `
  -Type gauge `
  -Help ' ' `
  -Labels 'Name'

$OfficeAvailabilityMetricDesc = New-MetricDescriptor `
  -Name 'Availability' `
  -Type gauge `
  -Help ' ' `
  -Labels 'Name'

$OfficeAvgResponseMetricDesc = New-MetricDescriptor `
  -Name 'AvgResponse' `
  -Type gauge `
  -Help ' ' `
  -Labels 'Name'

function collector {
  $Results = $Obj.d.results | 
    Select Name, 
    @{l="Utilization" ; e={$_.portmfs.portdata.im_Utilization}},
    @{l="Availability"; e={$_.portmfs.portdata.im_Availability}},
    @{l="AvgResponse" ; e={$_.icmpmfs.icmpresults.im_AvgResponseTime}}

  [array]$Metrics = $null
  foreach ($Result in $Results) {
    $Metric = New-Metric `
      -MetricDesc $OfficeUtilizationMetricDesc `
      -Value $Result.Utilization `
      -Labels $Result.Name

    $Metrics += $Metric

    $Metric = New-Metric `
      -MetricDesc $OfficeAvailabilityMetricDesc `
      -Value $Result.Availability`
      -Labels $Result.Name

    $Metrics += $Metric

    $Metric = New-Metric `
      -MetricDesc $OfficeAvgResponseMetricDesc `
      -Value $Result.AvgResponse`
      -Labels $Result.Name

    $Metrics += $Metric
  }

  $Metrics

}


$PrometheusExporter = New-PrometheusExporter -Port 9700
Register-Collector -Exporter $PrometheusExporter -Collector $Function:collector
$PrometheusExporter.Start()
```

The scraper data will now be available in native Prometheus ebnf format at http://localhost:9700/metrics (provided you opened that port in the local firewall).

Edit: I just noticed I provided the data in another order than asked about. :/ But you get the drift.